Display SVG in HTML same as WPF sharpvectors
We have an application made in WPF that uses sharpvectors to display a map as an SVG and now we need to display the same maps in HTML with blazor. The main issue is we place elements over the maps with a set of transforms and it looks as the SVGs are displayed differently between the two as with the same transforms elements don't align in HTML.
The best I can think is happening is that in WPF the blank space around the images are cropped out as just drawing the SVG in HTML has large padding.
Below are the examples, with the same transforms the HTML version is far over to the left


I've tried to process the SVG for HTML cropping the image using an online SVG cropper but that still results in the image being too far over.
I'm mostly looking for if anyone has any information on the differences between SVGs in WPF with sharpvector and HTML as I can't find any information, and I'm not well versed in WPF.

Please add some example SVG code showing the applied transforms. Quite likely, some transformation functions are not supported so rewriting them to a compatible format may do the trick.

Forget about WPF.  It's gone.  You're done with it.

Also: svg is NOT an image format.  It's a markup format, like HTML.  Don't try to manipulate svg with any kind of image editors (except Adobe Illustrator or other vector graphics apps)

You shouldn't add multiple svg objects to an html page.  You add a single svg object (for a game, make it cover the entire screen), and populate it with whatever shapes you need.  Because svg creates a canvas, positioning objects on that single canvas will be very easy.
I recommend making simple C# classes to represent whatever svg objects you want, and razor components to express them in markup.  The following is very simple, but should demonstrate the ideas.  Of course, you'll add parameters for stroke, fill, etc.
NOTE: ChatGPT can easily give you samples of svg primitives, and also convert them to C# classes.
Shapes.cs
 public class SvgShape(int draworder)
 {
     public int DrawOrder { get; set; } = draworder;
 }
 public class Circle(float cx, float cy, float r, int draworder) : SvgShape(draworder)
 {
     public float Cx { get; set; } = cx;
     public float Cy { get; set; } = cy;
     public float R { get; set; } = r;
     
 }
 public class Square(float x, float y, float width, float height, int draworder) : SvgShape(draworder)
 {
     public float X { get; set; } = x;
     public float Y { get; set; } = y;
     public float Width { get; set; } = width;
     public float Height { get; set; } = height;
 }

Home.razor
@page "/"
@using Code.Shapes
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
    <button @onclick=HandleCreate>Create</button>
    <svg style="width:250px; height:250px; border:1px solid red" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        @foreach (var shape in Shapes.OrderBy(s=>x.DrawOrder))
        {
            switch (shape)
            {
                case Circle c:
                    <SvgCircle Circle=c />
                    break;
                case Square s:
                    <SvgSquare Square=s />
                    break;
            }
        }
    </svg>
</div>

@code {
    List<SvgShape> Shapes = new();
    async Task HandleCreate()
    {
        Square baseRect = new Square(0, 0, 100f, 100f, 0);

        Circle c = new Circle(20f, 20f, 10f, 1);
        Square s = new Square(40f, 40f, 10f, 10f, 1);
        Shapes.Add(baseRect);
        Shapes.Add(c);
        Shapes.Add(s);
    }
}

SvgCircle.razor
@using Code.Shapes

<circle cx="@Circle.Cx" cy="@Circle.Cy" r="@Circle.R" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Circle Circle { get; set; }
}

SvgSquare.razor
@using Code.Shapes
<rect x="@Square.X" y="@Square.Y" width="@Square.Width" height="@Square.Height" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Square Square { get; set; }
}

